# How to delete multiple uploaded images in folder using PHP

Tags: php

How to delete multiple images in PHP.But Single product delete is working fine.

```php
if (isset($_REQUEST['delete_product'])) {
    $ca_in_id = $_REQUEST['delete_product'];
    $where = array("ca_in_id" => $ca_in_id);

    $data = $this->select_where('catalog_inventory', $where);
    //$res = $data->fetch_object();
    
    $result = $this->delete_where('catalog_inventory', $where);
    if ($result) {
        // (file_exists($pic1)) {
        //  print_r($pic1);
        // exit();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
            $image = $row["upload_file"];
            $pic1 = ("$image");
            unlink('product_images/' . $pic1);
            print_r($pic1);

        }
        exit();
        //}
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Delete Sucess");
            window.location = "list-product";
        </script>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
        <script>
            alert("Delete Fails");
            window.location = "list-product";
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

And multiple Image delete show this error :-

[image]

How to solve this issues?

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solve issues First get all values in database and using `explode` function use the `count` database columns values and use finally for loop.

**This My Code:-**

This code means is get values in database.

```
  $data = $this->select_where('catalog_inventory', $where);
  $res = $data->fetch_object();
  $image = $res->upload_file;
  $allimages = explode(",", $image);
  $countallimages = count($allimages);
```

After get multiple values and values run the looping

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < $countallimages; $i++) {
    if (file_exists("product_images/" . $allimages[$i]) == false) {
        echo "error ";
        exit();
    }
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $countallimages; $i++) {
    $path = "product_images/" . $allimages[$i];
    if (empty($path)) {
    } else {
        unlink($path);
    }
}
```

Thanks ...

Comment: Instead of counting the elements in the array, you can just [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) them.

Comment: How, can you explain me ?

Comment: Here's a more simplified version of your code: https://pastebin.com/6yNEtv7U. I put some comments, too. 

Also `$path` cannot be ever empty, as you are assigning a default value before checking with `empty()`. (Edited my snippet, used wrong variable while `unlink()`-ing).

Comment: Okay,i will try But  Thank you so much for Best guide 